# How to build millions of model for personalization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Let's say I'm building an app like Uber and I want to predict the user's most likely destination based on the user's past history, current latitude-longitude, and current date and time.

We have millions of users, but each user needs will be probably too unique for generalization. I.e., everyone's commute is so different that what you have learned from other users are probably not applicable to other users.

In conclusion, I have to build millions of models, how can I merge these models together for a better deployment process? If not, what are the best practices to deploy millions of models?

Answer (score 2):

> We have millions of users, but each user needs will be probably too unique for generalization.

You don't need to build millions of models. Create one model and Personalized it for every/each segment of users. As an example, Google personalized its applications such as Search engine, Youtube, and Play store based on users behaviors. Personalization not only can be for a single user but a group of them. For instance, Male and Female in Fitness application need to get different pieces of advice. In this case, it assumes you have two kinds of users.

*What does it mean by behaviors*? Your history of search, your information in Gmail account, your sessions, and many other things usually considered as user behavior.

Suggesting personalized information to the users is a well-known research problem which mainly recognized as [Recommender System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system).

> I have to build millions of models, how can I merge these models
>   together for a better deployment process

Merging models is another area of research called [Ensembling learing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). We usually ensemble 2 to 10 models but not millions.

Comment: "For example, Personalized it for a single user or more generally for a group of users. "
How to implements the Personalized it for a single user? To put userId as a feature for the model training?

Comment: @birdstar search about recommendation system. Your question is too broad to answer in a single SO question.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply!